# Code::Blocks console opens; does not actually run code

Tags: codeblocks

My Code::Blocks (version 17.12, I think this is the latest version) has been working fine for the last couple of months, but all of a sudden it won't run my code anymore.

When I press 'Build and run', a console window pops open as expected, but from then on nothing happens. Nothing is printed in it, not even if I wait for several full minutes.

At first I thought there might be some obscure problem with my particular code, but the problem persists across all projects. Even when I simply build the default Hello World program (an unedited newly-created project), it doesn't work.

The build log is no help either. It gives no indication that anything has gone wrong and in fact shows nothing out of the ordinary (apart from me closing the window after a while).

```
-------------- Build: Debug in simple_test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=c++14 -IC:\Users\[MY_NAME]\Documents\[PATH]\eigen-eigen-b3f3d4950030\eigen-eigen-b3f3d4950030 -c C:\Users\[MY_NAME]\Documents\[PATH]\simple_test\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\simple_test.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -O3  

-------------- Build: Debug in simple_test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\simple_test.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -O3  
Output file is bin\Debug\simple_test.exe with size 1.51 MB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))


-------------- Run: Debug in simple_test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: C:\Users\[MY_NAME]\Documents\[PATH]\simple_test\bin\Debug\simple_test.exe
Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe" "C:\Users\[MY_NAME]\Documents\[PATH]\simple_test\bin\Debug\simple_test.exe"  (in C:\Users\[MY_NAME]\Documents\[PATH]\simple_test\.)
Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 6 second(s))
```

I can't begin to fathom what's caused this problem, or even what changed on my computer that could have brought this on.

Edit: I'm still on Windows 8.

Edit: even a reinstall of Code::Blocks did not fix the issue, whereas a restart of my computer *did*. I have no idea what happened or why, but at least it's working for now.